# Show that Blaschke factors satisfy inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Theorem:
>
> Let $w, z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\bar{z}w \neq 1$. Then
> $$ |z| < 1 \land |w| < 1 \Rightarrow \left| \frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}\right| < 1$$

I tried to make $w = u +iv, z = x + iy$ and expand, but that did not give me useful results. How to prove it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Equivalently
$$|w-z|^2<|1-\bar{w}z|^2$$
i.e.
$$(w-z)(\bar{w}-\bar{z})<(1-\bar{w}z)(1-w\bar{z})$$
which is also equivalent to
$$|w|^2+|z|^2<1+|w|^2|z|^2$$
The above inequality can be written as
$$|w|^2(1-|z|^2)<1-|z|^2$$
which is always true for $|w|<1$, $|z|<1$.

Comment: On which step does it imply the condition for $|z|<1$ cannot be lifted?

Comment: @HenryW The last step. You need $1-|z|^2>0$ when you multiply both sides of $|w|^2<1$ so that the inequality direction  remains unchanged.